# My Batch file loop stops because of open file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to build a batch file that pings multiple devices on our network and continues logging ping results data in an output file in an infinite loop. However, the infinite loop gets hung up because the output file is open. Once I manually close the output file, the loop begins another iteration and logs more data. How do I automate this step? I've gone through so many options with taskkill, but none of them will close the output file for some reason. Other Notepad files close, but not the output file running on notepad.

Thanks for you help! Code is below:

```
@echo off
if exist C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\data\computers.txt goto Label1
echo.
echo Cannot find C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\data\computers.txt
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label1
:loop

echo ================================================= >> C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt
echo PingTest executed on %date% at %time% >> C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt
for /f %%i in (C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\data\computers.txt) do call :Sub %%i
notepad C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt
choice /n/t:c,<10>/c:cc
echo ================================================= >> C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt
start notepad.exe
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr notepad.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe > nul
goto loop
goto :eof

:Sub
echo Testing %1
ping -n 1 %1 >> C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt | find /i "(0% loss)" 
echo %1 Testing done
echo %1 Testing done >> C:\Users\Tsgadmin\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt
```

Comment: Actually it stops because you launched notepad directly and it's waiting for it to close. Also, what are you trying to do with `choice /n/t:c,<10>/c:cc`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I removed the line: start notepad.exe but the code has the same issue.

Comment: Seriously though... What is it you're trying to accomplish with `choice /n/t:c,<10>/c:cc`?

Comment: A ten second delay before the loop's next iteration

Comment: I'd recommend using `TIMEOUT` then.

Comment: @3D1T0R `choice /n/t:c,<10>/c:cc` is most likely just the wrong approach for a 10 seconds wait. Since Windows 7 there is the command [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) for such wait tasks. But perhaps this batch file is written for Windows XP on which `choice /C yn /N /T 10 /D y >nul` would really work.

Comment: @Mofi: I figured it might be, but wanted verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your batch code rewritten for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LogFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ping_firepanels_output.txt"
set "ListFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\data\computers.txt"

if exist "%ListFile%" goto PrepareForPings
echo/
echo Cannot find file: "%ListFile%"
echo/
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

rem Delete existing log file before running the echo requests.
rem Get just file name with file extension without path from
rem log file name with path specified at top of the batch file.

:PrepareForPings
del "%LogFile%" 2>nul
for /F %%I in ("%LogFile%") do set "LogFileName=%%~nxI"

rem Always terminate (not kill) running Notepad instance with having
rem the log file opened for viewing before running first/next test run.

:PingLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %LogFileName% - Notepad" >nul 2>nul

echo =================================================>>"%LogFile%"
>>"%LogFile%" echo PingTest executed on %DATE% at %TIME%
echo/>>"%LogFile%"

for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("%ListFile%") do (
    echo Testing %%I ...
    %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 -w 500 %%I>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%I is not available in network (no reply^).>>"%LogFile%"
    ) else echo %%I is available.>>"%LogFile%"
    echo %%I testing done.
)

echo =================================================>>"%LogFile%"
echo/>>"%LogFile%"

start "" %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe "%LogFile%"
echo/
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /T 10 /D Y /M "Run again (Y/n): "
echo/
if errorlevel 2 goto PingLoop
endlocal
```

In general it is advisable to define environment variables with names of files specified multiple times in the batch file at top to make it easier to modify them in future.

On referencing those file environment variables it is strongly recommended to enclose the name in double quotes to get a working batch file also when file name with path contains a space character or one of these characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

If a file name enclosed in double quotes is specified as text file of which lines to read in a `for /F` command line, it is necessary to use option `usebackq` to get interpreted the file name enclosed in double quotes as file name and not as string to process by **FOR**.

The DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) explains why it is better to use `echo/` instead of `echo.` to output an empty line.

The **TASKKILL** command used to send **Notepad** the terminate signal for a graceful termination should be send only to the **Notepad** instance having the log file opened and not any other perhaps running **Notepad** instance.

An **ECHO** line redirected to a file with `>` or `>>` with a space left to redirection operator results in having this space also written as trailing space into the file. For that reason there should be no space between text to write into the file and redirection operator. A space right to `>` or `>>` would be no problem as not written into the file.

When a variable text is output on an **ECHO** line redirected into a file which could end with `1`, `2`, `3`, ... `9`, it is necessary to specify the redirection from **STDOUT** into the file with `>>` at beginning of the line as otherwise `1>>`, `2>>`, ... would be interpreted different as expected on execution of the **ECHO** command line. Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

There is no subroutine necessary for this task. A command block starting with opening parenthesis `(` and matching `)` can be used here too. That makes the execution of the loop a bit faster, not really noticeable faster, but nevertheless faster.

There is a text written with `echo` into the log file containing also a closing parenthesis `)` not within a double quoted string. This `)` would be interpreted as matching `)` for opening `(` of true branch of **IF** condition. It is necessary to escape `)` with caret character `^` to get `)` interpreted as literal character by Windows command interpreter.

**PING** exits with exit code `1` if the *echo* request was not replied. Otherwise on successful reply the exit code is `0`. It is better to evaluate the exit code via `errorlevel` than filtering the language dependent output.

New instance of **Notepad** with the log file to view is started by this batch file using command `start` to run **Notepad** in a separate process running parallel to command process executing the batch file. Otherwise the execution of the batch file would be halted as long as the started **Notepad** instance is not closed by the user. That different behavior can be easily seen on removing `start ""` at beginning of the command line starting **Notepad**.

The command **CHOICE** gives the user of the batch file the possibility to exit the loop by pressing key <kbd>N</kbd> (case-insensitive) within 10 seconds. Otherwise the user prompt is automatically answered with choice `Y` and the loop is executed once again by first terminating running **Notepad**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ping /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`

See also [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for details on environment variables `USERPROFILE` and `SystemRoot` as used in this batch file.