# Issue with special character in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, special-characters, ping

A bit issue I can't solve.

In my for /f delims parameters, I have a special character `<` and my script doesn't notice it.

This script test network for IT needs. It logs disconnect network and speed.

```
set /p IP="IP : "
set /p MS="Millisecond : "
for /f "tokens=1,7 delims==< " %%a in ('ping.exe -w 1000 -n 1 %IP% ^| findstr /i /c:"temps"^|^| echo "Ne Repond Pas"') do (
 if "%%b" == "" (
 echo "%date% %time:~,8% Ne repond pas" >> log_%IP%.txt 
 ) ELSE (
  if %%b GEQ %MS% ( 
   echo "%date% %time:~,8% ms=%%b" >> log_%IP%.txt 
   timeout /t 1 > NUL 
  ) 
 ) 
) 
goto loop
```

When the ping result is < 1ms, it logs in the file. When the ping is =1ms or =2ms ... it works perfectly.

I try with the escape character `^` before `<` but that didn't work.

E.g

[Ping 8.8.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTjBx.jpg) : The log file is perfect because there isn't `<` in the result

[Ping 127.0.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcSD9.jpg) : The script logs in file

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to show us some typical output lines that "work" or "don't work" since you are evidently not using English (and hence the `ping` output format may be slightly different). I simply `edit`ed your code to standard format - I've no idea what the `^|^|echo...` is about - please explain. Have you displayed `%%a` and `%%b` using an `echo` for the problem conditions?

Comment: @oasisck What you are doing here to determine if the ping was successful or not is awful. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707214/3074564) with a batch code for very similar task to yours using exit code of `ping` for logging and explaining additionally in detail how this code works.

Comment: What is `%MS%` set to? Since `<` is a delimiter, it cannot occur in `%%a` or `%%b`; hence the problem must be somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all

I found my problem, and F*** Windows...

The result in ping is slighlty different when the result is `<1ms` or higher like `=33 ms`

Note the space.

I just adapt my code with

```
for /f "tokens=1,8 delims=m=^< " %%a in ('ping.exe -w 1000 -n 1 %IP% ^| findstr /i /c:"temps"^|^| echo "Ne Repond Pas"') do (
```

And it works